# 502 error while converting entity framework data to json. Possible recursion. How to prevent it?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

```
[HttpGet("/api/notes/suggested")]
    public JsonResult GetSuggestedNotes(string searchText)
    {
        //TODO: Podpowiedzi przy wpisywaniu tytułu
        JsonResult result = null;
        try {
            List<Note> n = db.Notes.Include(x => x.NoteTags).ToList();

            result = Json(n);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
        }
        return result;
    }

public class Note
    {
        public Note()
        {
            CreationDate = DateTime.Now;
            NoteTags = new HashSet<NoteTag>();
            Parts = new HashSet<Part>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<NoteTag> NoteTags { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Part> Parts { get; set; }
        public DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string TagsToAdd { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public string TagsAsSingleString {
            get
            {
                string result = "";
                foreach(var nt in NoteTags)
                {
                    result += nt.Tag.Name + " ";
                }
                return result;
            }
        }
    }

public class NoteTag
    {
        public int NoteId { get; set; }
        public virtual Note Note { get; set; }

        public int TagId { get; set; }
        public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    }
```

When I try to get data using this WebAPI controller, I get 502 bad gateway. No errors, everything's fine while debugging server. Data get from database correctly.

I suspect that it could be something similar to "infinite loop" but how to prevent it? (Note class is connected to collection of NoteTag objects that are connected back to Note which probably makes this loop).

And why there are no errors if something went wrong? :/

Comment: It could be you way have a haywire Gateway computer; OTOH, you might want to czech out http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E502.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it still relevant but i had the same problem and what worked for me it to Configure Newtonsoft.Json 
    **SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ewtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore**.

If you are using VS2015 MVC you can add the following code:
    *services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore);*

in the **ConfigureServices** method in the **Startup** class.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem its recursion, can you try with an Anonymous type
NoteTags has Note , imagine if the Note->NoteTags->Note->NoteTags->Note->NoteTags ...

`List n = db.Notes.Include(x => x.NoteTags).ToList();

var e = n.select(x=> new {property=value});

result = Json(e);`

Comment: so... what should I do to prevent recursion? What does your code do and what is "property" and "value"?

Comment: first you have to do is see wich information is what you really need. then you create a Anonymous  for example var e = n.select(x=> new {NoteName=x.name});

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. Still doesn't work, because when I type "NoteTags = x.NoteTags", the code behaves the same way as before. Infinite loop.

Comment: whichs properties you need from NoteTags? you can do something like "NoteTagsName = x.NoteTags.Name"

Comment: In fact I can't. This is collection of objects

Comment: if NoteTags has Note why you not try to start from db.NoteTags instead from db.Note